# What do Rear-End Collision Avoidance System do on Ice?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I read on [itworld.com](http://www.itworld.com/article/2826935/networking/11-cutting-edge-car-tech-innovations.html?page=3):

> Companies such as Volvo and Mercedes are working on crash avoidance systems. Radar measures the distance to obstacles ahead of the car, and if one comes too close the system will warn the driver. If the driver fails to act in sufficient time to stop the car safely, the cars computer takes over and applies the brakes.

Is anyone working on making the cars respond sooner at colder temperatures, or when the road appears to be in slippery conditions? (car has less traction, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

That would either not be feasible, or make no sense. There is no effective, economical and safe way to test for "slippery conditions" before the fact. Once the car starts to brake, its ABS systems will automatically detect the exact road conditions, and do the best they can under those conditions. Cold temperatures by themselves do not significantly affect braking/stopping performance. Conversely, there are many road conditions that are not temperature-related that significantly affect braking performance also.

Comment: I think your absolutist answer is a bit short sighted. I think something that adjusts stopping distances/top speeds in wet conditions is entirely feasible (and easily detectible).

Although off the top of my head I can't think of a way to detect ice, I would certainly not go as far as saying it's 'not feasible'. I mean we can measure ocean salinity from space!  Surely we can measure road conditions 10m in front of a car. haha

Comment: @ashgetstazered We can measure a lot of things; but measuring them on the fly and reacting appropriately is a different problem, sometimes requiring tools you'd never fit in a consumer vehicle.

Comment: I agree that there are some sensors that are too pricey. Something that measures how wet a road is though? Come on. Not hard. Not expensive. Definitely possible. I'm just saying this absolutist answer of saying it's not possible to adjust a cars driving system to the conditions is plain wrong.